# Automatically load modules or libraries in Laravel controller or model

Tags: php, laravel, autoload

In my Laravel project, many Controllers and Models have the same headers.
For example, they all include

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use DB;
```

So, each time I ever create a new Controller, I have to insert the same header part. (like above)

Is there any way to autoload the above libraries in all controllers and models?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a base class which accepts the dependencies in the constructor.

You could also create a Container class which reduces the amount of direct dependencies you have in a controller :

```php
class Container
{
    public function __construct(/* Your dependencies */) {
        /* Set dependencies */
    }

    /* Dependency getters */
}
```

Controller:

```php
class MyController 
{
    public function __construct(Container $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function index() {
         /* Access dependencies on container */   
    }
}
```

But to be honest if you depend on request in a model class you have done something wrong. Typically in MVC the request info is passed from within the controller to the model, so the model does not know about the Request object, the values from Request are passed through as primitive values or value objects.

### Update to explain my answer

You can reduce the amount of dependencies in your model classes (which is the best option) by simply following these rules, as explained here: https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html

So for example instead of writing:

```php
//Note this is not a laravel specific example
class MyModel
{
    private $request;
    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function getInfo()
    {
        return /* find info on $request->get('id'); */
    }
}
```

You can write:

```php
class MyController
{
    public function __construct(MyModel $myModel)
    {
        $this->myModel = $myModel;
    }
    
    public function index()
    {
        $info = $this->myModel->getInfo($this->getRequest()->get('id'));
    }
}
```

Where Request dependency is now removed from the Model:

```php
//Note this is not a laravel specific example
class MyModel
{

    public function getInfo(int $id)
    {
        return /* find info on $id; */
    }
}
```

This was the simplest explanation, it will get more complex, so the best idea is to read and understand the article.

Comment: Thanks for answering. but I am finding a way like CodeIgniter's autoload function.